# Displaying code snippets from WordPress custom fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to display code snippets entered into my custom field. An example code snippet entered into custom field - `snippet-1`

```
<?php
if (($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count)) {
   echo '<div class="post-item-divider">Post Divider</div>';
}
?>
```

If I try to display this code wrapped in `<pre></pre>` tags in my page template like

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snippet-1', true) ) : ?>
    <pre><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snippet-1', true) ?></pre>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but it returns nothing to the template. I understand WordPress is filtering the snippet out as it sees as PHP code to execute. Is there a way just to print this out on the page as a code snippet?

Many thanks in advance

rob

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape your code.

**Update**

```
echo htmlspecialchars(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snippet-1', true));
```

Comment: Thankyou. How would I go about applying htmlspecialchars() to `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snippet-1', true) ?>`. Many thanks rob